# How to doxygen comment function with Q_INVOKABLE

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qdoc

For example, I have two functions A & B like:

```
void aFunction();

Q_INVOKABLE void bFunction();
```

Enter `/**` before function delcaration and press `enter`:

```
 /**
 * @brief A
 */
void aFunction();

/**
Q_INVOKABLE void bFunction();
```

Is this a BUG?

OS: Windows 7
QtCreator Version: 3.1.2 and 4.3.1

Comment: It pertains to Qt Creator. Looks like there is a problem. Neither /** nor /// working in that case.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Windows 7 with Qt Creator 4.4.0

Comment: I tried on Linux with 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is:

First, write like:

```
Q_INVOKABLE

void aFunction();
```

Then enter `/**` above the function.

```
Q_INVOKABLE
/**
 * @brief aFunction
 */
void aFunction();
```